# Query WordPress Posts and put Titles in Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to query my WordPress for a specific post type "team_members" and then store the titles in an array. When I use the following my output just shows 0, 1, 2 (I only have the 3 posts) it doesn't show the post titles.

```
 $my_array=array();

// the query
$args=array('post_type' => 'team_members','order'=>'ASC');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    $my_array[]=get_the_title( get_the_ID() );
endwhile;
endif;
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
John

Comment: you do not need `get_the_ID()`, and specify on order by.

Comment: I ran this code through a personal wordpress install. Only changing the post type to one of mine, and adding a print_r($my_array); between the endwhile and endif; It came out with an array of post titles as expected. tldr; your code works...

You may want to check where you initiate the post type, check various settings and arguments. Are you calling this before or after wp_head() or get_header() ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try replacing

```
get_the_title(get_the_ID());
```

with

```
the_title();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,

Your right it does work, I think it was the way I was trying to use the variable in Visual Composer. When I use the variable in a drop down box I see the titles correctly but when I use it for multiple checkboxes it displays the post ID.

It's a Visual Composer issue.

Thanks Mauro as the_title(); did simplify the code and also worked for me.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your code. Try using get posts and using the post_title property instead.

E.g.

```
$my_array = array();

// the query
$args=array('post_type' => 'team_members','order'=>'ASC');

$posts = get_posts( $args );

if ( $posts ) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $my_array[] = $post->post_title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// the query
$args=array('post_type' => 'team_members','order'=>'ASC');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $id = $my_query->posts->ID; 
    $my_array[]=get_the_title( $id );
endwhile;
endif;
```